# Emacs check syntax of file before saving

Tags: emacs, text-editing

How I can prevent Emacs from saving my buffer when it contains syntax errors ?

It would by especially useful for editing source code.

I'm writing some source code into the buffer, hit C-x C-s and Emacs should position the cursor on the line containing the error. I'm correcting the error, hit the save command again, and Emacs should save the file.

Comment: You do not say what sources you would like to check. There are different tools for different types. And ways these can be integrated into emacs.

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this problem would be to rebind C-x C-s to `astropanic-save-buffer` which would be an elisp function that would run the contents of the current buffer through whatever your compiler/build process is. If it passed, it would run `save-buffer` and if there was an error it would create a new buffer/window split with the error message so you could fix it.

Consider also using the `write-file-functions`([more info](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Saving-Buffers.html)) hook to attach workflow to `save-buffer`, but I'm wary of this on the grounds that while I might think that I'd want this in some modes, I wouldn't in all modes.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs [flymake](http://flymake.sourceforge.net/) mode may be close to what you want. It does dynamic compiling/syntax checking of source code for the current buffer.